# How to visualise backlog items which must be pushed to done every day

Tags: kanban, user-stories, kanban-board

Has anyone found a good method that doesn’t feel lame about representing activities that need to be completed every day on a personal or team kanban board.

For instance, if I wanted to read every day and exercise.

It somehow feels lame but at the same time I like to know it’s on my list every day and it feels good to push it to done.

Comment: Should it be a board? I think checklists are better for this. Then unchecking all the items in the morning. Or cloning the checklist every day, then also adding one-off tasks which you know should be done today. But this probably isn't the topic for PM SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a preference for any particular software tool? In [Trello](https://trello.com/) for example you can use the Card Repeater feature to have new backlog items created automatically every day, week or month.

Comment: I don’t know Trello did this! This would be perfect because I already use Trello

Comment: [Trello Card Repeater](https://trello.com/power-ups/57b47fb862d25a30298459b1)

Comment: Great thanks awwwwesome!

Answer (score 1):

I have seen people with a separate board in the shape of a circle, and the cards go round and round like hands on a clock. But I don't consider such things to belong on a Kanban system.